# Get Selected UV vertices coordinates

Tags: python, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to get the coordinates for the selected UV vertices with this script:

```
import bpy


mesh = bpy.context.object.data

uv = mesh.uv_layers.active.data

print(uv[0].uv)
```

But unfortunately the coordinates printed in the console are always the same regardless of what vertices I select.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

---

here is the code to get the coordinates for the selected vertices in the UV/Image editor :

```
import bpy
import bmesh

def main(context):
    obj = context.active_object
    me = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

    uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.verify()
    bm.faces.layers.tex.verify()

    for f in bm.faces:
        for l in f.loops:
            luv = l[uv_layer]
            if luv.select:
                #print the coordinates
                print(luv.uv)

    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: May I ask why aren't you just getting the coordinates from the UV/Image Editor?

Comment: @sekce I want write a script that calculate the angle between the selected vertices(edge) and the x or y axis then align the island depending on the calculated angle, and in order to calculate the angle I need to get the coordinates of the vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in your Blender will help you, see.
Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator Mesh Uv